# Unable to locate element from webdriver whereas IDE locates it

Tags: selenium, ide, webdriver

Please find the code below :

```
<table class="cctable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" tabindex="0" summary="Content">
<thead id="Header">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<td class="tableText" nowrap="" height="10">
<td width="1" height="15">
<td class="tableText" nowrap="" height="10">
<td width="1" height="15">
<td class="tableText" width="100%" height="10" wrap="true" style="background-color: transparent;">
<a href="/tarf/servlet/dispatch?b_action=xts.run&m=portal/cc.xts&m_folder=iED96C06121E44804B62901EB41BCAEC2">**Hyper-V**</a>
</td>
<td width="1" height="15">
<td class="tableText" width="200" nowrap="" height="10">
<td width="1" height="15">
<td class="tableText" width="170" nowrap="" height="10">
</tr>
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr style="height:1px">
<tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

---

I am trying to click on the link "Hyper-V" on the UI.

I have tried css, xpath , name , id , all the possible locators and all the locators work when I try to find it through selenium IDE 2.5.0.The element get flashed when i evaluate.

However , when I put the same locator in my webdriver script and try to locate it , it throws "NoSuchElementException" everytime.can anyone suggest me how to go with this?
How to know if locating elements on our UI is supported by Selelnium or Do we have any limitations.

Let me know your suggestions/Ideas.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried through xpath and it worked `//a[text()='**Hyper-V**']`
FireFox + FireBug + FirePath

IMG: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/07/07/333/7cc/fea637f96e0087660354dcce74cdea55e17fdf16.jpg

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrian,Thanks for you reply.
I am able to locate my element this way usnig xpath or css , however my concern is when i put this xpath or css in my webdriver code and execute it says "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()='**Hyper-V**']"}

Not sure if this could be a limitation with my application supporting selenium webdriver, as this works fine with Selenium IDE and able to click on the located element with the above xpath.

Comment: try //a[contains(text(),'Hyper-V')]

Comment: Hi Andrian, Thanks
Tried with the given xpath, even this does not work on execution , getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe your element didn't is dynamic, try when you are searching your element to print out page source and search there your Hyper-V, driver.getPageSource(), if you will not found then add wait time for it.

Comment: Hi , I have added the following lines to my code :
String Source = driver.getPageSource( );
if (Source.contains("Hyper-V"))
{
System.out.println("PASS");
}
else
{
System.out.println("FAIL");
}
I got the FAIL message always.i have added wait time as well.
However in the source search i found the frame source, Its in a frame and I have tried to switch to the frame by ID and then find element but still no luck.

Comment: you can find the frame source code:
<iframe id="_N1860883243_iframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width:100%;height:100%;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" loadurl="/ss/console/contentRender.do?oid=_N1860883243&pageid=com.ibm.tivoli.reporting.advanced.cognos.portlet.navigationElement;com.ibm.tivoli.reporting.advanced.cognos.portlet&XSS=wSSqqtF-ux570xpdLHEgF1D" src="/ibm/console/contentRender.do?oid=_N1860883243&

Comment: pageid=com.ibm.tivoli.reporting.advanced.cognos.portlet.navigationElement;com.ibm.tivoli.reporting.advanced.cognos.portlet&XSS=wSSqqtF-ux570xpdLHEgF1D" name="isc_iframe" onload="SMUtils.IF_OnIFrameLoad(document.getElementById('_N1860883243_iframe'))" isnosize="false" title="Content frame">
Tried to switch to the frame by id and name , no luck.

Comment: Hi, I think that your iframe has dynamic ID, try to find the container where is your iframe xpath = //div//iframe, then after switch try to get source page again and see what you got

Comment: Hi Andrian , I tired to get the container of iframe and locate it with xpath , however it is unable to locate the container itself.
throws "unable to locate element exception".
Added this code :
  Boolean bool = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#_N1860883243")).isSelected();
  System.out.println(bool);
and this was returning FALSE.

Comment: .isSelected() - is for checkbox, try int nrIframe = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'_N') and contains(@id,'_iframe')]")).size(), if (iframe > 0) { System.out.println("FOUND");} after that you save element, WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'_N') and contains(@id,'_iframe')]")); and switch to it driver.switchTo().frame(iframe); System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrian, I have copied the code and tried executing, It printed "FOUND" and the frame source code, however the required link text "Hyper-V" was not found in the code.It did not had any of the element names of the frame either except the window title.
The code has HTML and Java script with some functions defined.

Comment: I don't have page source or URL from your site so I can't really help you, sorry.